The Ending of "No Longer Human"
In the final quote by the bartender of the Kyobashi, she pins the blame of Yozo's personality on his father. Which, to me, feels a bit out of place.

It's his father's fault," she said unemotionally. "The Yozo we knew
was so easy-going and amusing, and if only he hadn't drunk—no, even
though he did drink—he was a good boy, an angel."

Yozo, or Dazai, mentions his father probably no more than five times in the novel, and it's true that he, for some reason, always mentions him with a notion of fear. An idea, which I believe was properly explained, why was Yozo so fearful of his father that he wrote this on his death?

The news of my father's death eviscerated me. He was dead, that
familiar, frightening presence who had never left my heart for a split
second. I felt as though the vessel of my suffering had become empty,
as if nothing could interest me now. I had lost even the ability to
suffer.

Therefore, I am finding it difficult to understand why the bartender blamed Yozo's father for the way Yozo turned out.

No Longer Human was written in 1948, when psychology tended to put the blame for everything on the parents. I don't know how widespread knowledge of these psychological theories was in Japan, but if the author (or the bartender) subscribed to them, then blaming his father is understandable.

@PeterShor But if we consider that "No Longer Human" is the world take of Dazai, in that the feelings of Yozo are the feelings of Dazai then the question becomes, "Is Dazai blaming his father?". What do you think about it?

I'd have to read the book to really say more — which is why my thoughts were a comment and not an answer.

Maybe you can have a look at this with machine translation. But I don't think there's much why. I guess it simply suggests he was oppressed by his father. Such a father was not so uncommon in those days.

Dazai blaming father should be one possible interpretation.

@sundowner I think the blog you have attached in your comment answers more than you think. The author of the blog post shares quotes from Dazai's other book, Memories, based on those quotes and Yozo's feelings towards his father, you can see how correlated both the figures are -- Yozo's father and Dazai's father. From the quotes, I believe that Dazai blames his father for the way he turned out, and he empathises with Yozo by making the shopkeeper blame the father -- even though she never knew Yozo's father.

I agree that the madam’s comment feels out of place, but that’s not so much because of the comment but because of the fact that it’s the first time we hear a different narrator.
Yozo is relentless in his self-mortification. No one is harder on him, than he is himself. The comment I feel is about that. A reminder to the reader that Yozo’s awfulness mainly existed in his own head. That he is not weird, the way he seems to think of himself as weird.
The book is about alienation and how it wrecks mental health. And distorts perception and ideas of self worth.
But yeah the similarities between the author and Yozo are there so it’s hard to argue the author was trying to offer some form of redemption.
